# Creating modulo formula to convert numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I need a formula that makes the following conversion from a to b:

```
a    b
0 -> 2
1 -> 3
2 -> 4
3 -> 5
4 -> 6
5 -> 7
6 -> 1
```

By trial and error, I came up with the the following formula:
$$b = (a + 1) \,\text{mod } 7 + 1$$

How to come up with the equation in a systematic manner?

Background: The problem originates from converting weekdays from zero-indexed (with Monday first) system to [Java Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)'s one-indexed (with [Sunday](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.SUNDAY) first).

Comment: Feel free to edit the terminology in the title and question itself, and add tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that $a$ ranges from $0$ to $6$, inclusive, so there must be a `modulo $7$' sort of thing involved. Also, $b$ ranges from $1$ to $7$, which is the same as $a$'s range, but with a $1$ added. Subtracting this extra $1$, we observe that $b$ is still one greater than $a$, modulo $7$, and hence the formula.